# App showing in search but can't access

Tags: facebook

I can see my app in search, but when i click it i get an page not found error, also I get a page not found error when trying to view insights. I wonder whats wrong?

my app name:Small Circles

url:http://mysmallcircles.appspot.com/

profile page:http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=129200773829451

THX~!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the bookmark url in the app settings. This has been logged with Facebook already: http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=20469